# Unity - C# Trying to change a tag of an item in one list when an object in another list is destroyed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Recently took an online course on beginner c# w/ unity and unfortunately the instructor ended the course with a broken and unfinished code.  Having about 3 weeks of experience under my belt, I decided to learn, research, and make a viable build before moving on.

I've got two lists and a variable:

```
private List<Widget> WidgetList = new List<Widget>();
private List<Collider2D> ItemList = new List<Collider2D>();
private Collider2D itemSpot;
```

I then have an if statement inside the update method that, upon clicking the left mouse button the code changes the tag of the item clicked, adds that item to a `ItemList`, and generates a new Widget in that location.

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
        Vector2 worldPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast (worldPoint, Vector2.zero);
        if (hit.collider.tag == "BlankItem") {
            itemSpot = hit.collider;
            itemSpot.tag = "FullItem";
            RegisterItemSpot (itemSpot);
            MakeWidget (hit);
         }
}
```

This currently works fine, albeit I get the impression it was not the most ideal code (was not a well made course).  The call to the `RegisterItemSpot` and `MakeWidget` methods work flawlessly, each properly uses the .Add to their respective lists.  At the end of the game, I've got a method that also clears both lists without a problem.

Here is my hurdle:  If I destroy a single instance of a Widget, I would like the itemSpot that was associated with it to change its tag to `"BlankItem"` again.  I used a similar function to the previous to destroy the Widget:

```
 void Update (){
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
            Vector2 worldPointt = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit2D hitt = Physics2D.Raycast (worldPointt, Vector2.zero);
            if (hitt.collider.tag == "Tower" && destroyMode != false)
                Destroy(hitt.transform.gameObject);

            }

        }
```

From there in the `OnDestroy` of the Widget class i have it remove itself from the list, and that works fine too.

In my head I imagine a couple lines of code that, within the `OnDestroy` of the Widget, would rename the `itemSpot` that was initially associated with that specific destroyed Widget. I don't know how to associate the new Widget with the specific `itemSpot`.  Something along the lines of "if this object is destroyed, then the object associated with THAT collider gets retagged". The few ideas I have would require rebuilding this code from the ground up (maybe making arrays instead of lists?)and I feel like my novice brain would be better served just moving on to my next course instead of taking all that time.  Maybe not?  I just need some advice from more experienced folks.  If i need to provide more information, please let me know (10 classes of hundreds of code seemed like too much to just throw on here).

**EDIT:** Ive included the MakeWidget() method and the RegisterItemSpot() and RegisterWidget() methods.  I should have from the get-go, very sorry!

```
    public void MakeWidget (RaycastHit2D hit){
    if (!EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject) {
        Tower newWidget = Instantiate (widgetBtnPressed.WidgetObject);
        newWidget.transform.position = hit.transform.position;
        RegisterWidget (newWidget);
        widgetBtnPressed = null;}
    }
    public void RegisterItemSpot (Collider2D itemSpot){
    ItemList.Add(itemSpot);
    }
    public void RegisterWidget (Widget widget)
    {
    WidgetList.Add(widget);
    }
```

Comment: Could you also post the code containing the makewidget and registeritemspot code.

Comment: I dont actually know how to notify you that I made the edits (maybe this comment?) but I added the methods you requested.  Currently, they work as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best approach is creating a new containerclass, and then declaring a new list of said class. Here is an example

```
public class WidgetContainer()
{
    public Widget widget;
    public Collider2D collider;
}
```

Then replace your two lists with this one

```
public List<WidgetContainer> widgetContainers = new List<WidgetContainer>();
```

Then merge your makewidget and registeritemspot method into one method and create and add a new WidgetContainer to the list. Now you will always have a connection stored between these two variables.

```
var newContainer = new WidgetContainer
{
    widget = newWidget,
    collider = itemSpot
}
```

Finally in your OnDestroy() of the said widget as you describe, you can do this:

```
widgetContainers.First(x => x == this).collider.tag = "your tag here";
```

"this" references to instance of the class. In your case this would be your Widgetscript.

Do not that you will need to add this using statement at the top of your script for Linq.

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: This is awesome advice and it really opens my newbie eyes to a lot.  Thank you so much, friend!!

Comment: Anytime. Glad i could help